# Getting not valid month in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sqlplus, to-date

I have a table called `Transactions` that has a column called `trans_date`. I am just trying to do a simple query in the SQL*Plus command window

The query is

```sql
SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE 
trans_date BETWEEN to_date('09/11/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('09/12/2021','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

When I run this query I get not valid month and there is a little `*` under `trans_date`. Most of what I have read suggests the query is right but I am not sure what the problem is. The data type is varchar2(20).

Comment: yes that's a typo its yyyy

Comment: Perhaps the data type of the trans_date column is wrong?  Can't really tell from the information you've given.

Comment: the Datatype is varchar2(20)

Comment: Why is it varchar2 and not date? That will make everything harder and make all kinds of bugs possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `trans_date` is a `varchar` and you're trying to query whether it's between two `date`s, you need to convert it to a `date` too. Assuming it has the same format as the literals in your query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   transactions 
WHERE  to_date(trans_date, 'mm/dd/yyy') BETWEEN 
       to_date('09/11/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('09/12/2021','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is columns data type, Try convert it to date,

```
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE to_date(trans_date,'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN to_date('09/11/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('09/12/2021','mm/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `trans_date` to a date.  However, you can use date constants for the comparisons:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE to_date(trans_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN DATE '2021-09-11' AND DATE '2021-09-12';
```

You should fix your data model so the dates are stored correctly, using Oracle's built-in data type.